# Xalan link failure using libraries built from source

Tags: c++, xml, xalan, xerces-c

I am upgrading one of our libraries to the latest version. The xalan from GitHub at https://github.com/apache/xalan-c. I was able to compile this library successfully using gcc 12. And when I ran make test command, it was all OK. But when used it in my code and it will fail when try to link, I got errors like this (I did check the library search path, both libxalan-c.so and libxalanMsg.so can be found by the ld):

```
    g++   -g -O0  -Werror -Wunused -Wall -D__USE_XOPEN2K8 -D_REENTRANT -D__STL_PTHREADS -std=c++17 -pthread -Wno-parentheses -Wno-nonnull -pipe -lxerces-c -L/rapid/rapid_workspaces/chuhuan/GitHub/xalan-c/build/lib64/ -lxalan-c -lxalanMsg -Lxxxxxxxxx/TargetRTS/ -ldhf
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: linux/TargetRTS/ParamConfig.o: in function `dhf::DataHandlerFactory::initializeXMLLibs()':
xxxxxxxxx/DataHandlerFactory.hh:58: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanTransformer::initialize(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DataHandlerFactory.hh:59: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XPathEvaluator::initialize(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/TargetRTS//libdhf.a(DOMImpl.o): in function `dhf::DOMImpl::transform(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:173: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesParserLiaison::XercesParserLiaison(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:183: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(char16_t const*, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&, unsigned long)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:184: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesDOMWrapperParsedSource::XercesDOMWrapperParsedSource(xercesc_4_0::DOMDocument const*, xalanc_1_12::XercesParserLiaison&, xalanc_1_12::XercesDOMSupport&, xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString const&, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:190: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::FormatterToXercesDOM::FormatterToXercesDOM(xercesc_4_0::DOMDocument*, xercesc_4_0::DOMElement*, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:191: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanTransformer::XalanTransformer(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:192: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XSLTResultTarget::XSLTResultTarget(xalanc_1_12::FormatterListener&, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:192: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XSLTInputSource::XSLTInputSource(char const*, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/TargetRTS//libdhf.a(DOMImpl.o): in function `dhf::DOMImpl::get(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, double*)':
xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:237: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesParserLiaison::XercesParserLiaison(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:244: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesParserLiaison::createDocument(xercesc_4_0::DOMDocument const*, bool, bool, bool)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:246: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(char const*, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&, unsigned long)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:248: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XPathEvaluator::XPathEvaluator(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:250: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XPathEvaluator::evaluate(xalanc_1_12::DOMSupport&, xalanc_1_12::XalanNode*, char16_t const*, xalanc_1_12::XalanElement const*)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/TargetRTS//libdhf.a(DOMImpl.o): in function `dhf::DOMImpl::getSize(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int*)':
xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:298: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesParserLiaison::XercesParserLiaison(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:305: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesParserLiaison::createDocument(xercesc_4_0::DOMDocument const*, bool, bool, bool)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:307: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(char const*, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&, unsigned long)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:309: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XPathEvaluator::XPathEvaluator(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:313: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XPathEvaluator::selectSingleNode(xalanc_1_12::DOMSupport&, xalanc_1_12::XalanNode*, char16_t const*, xalanc_1_12::XalanElement const*)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/TargetRTS//libdhf.a(DOMImpl.o): in function `dhf::DOMImpl::get(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:364: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesParserLiaison::XercesParserLiaison(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:371: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesParserLiaison::createDocument(xercesc_4_0::DOMDocument const*, bool, bool, bool)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:373: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(char const*, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&, unsigned long)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:375: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XPathEvaluator::XPathEvaluator(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:377: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XPathEvaluator::evaluate(xalanc_1_12::DOMSupport&, xalanc_1_12::XalanNode*, char16_t const*, xalanc_1_12::XalanElement const*)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/TargetRTS//libdhf.a(DOMImpl.o): in function `dhf::DOMImpl::serialize(std::ostream&)':
xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:486: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanStdOutputStream::XalanStdOutputStream(std::ostream&, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:490: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:490: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:490: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:490: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:490: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/TargetRTS//libdhf.a(DOMImpl.o):xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:490: more undefined references to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)' follow
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/TargetRTS//libdhf.a(DOMImpl.o): in function `dhf::DOMImpl::serialize(std::ostream&)':
xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:490: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::FormatterToXML::FormatterToXML(xalanc_1_12::Writer&, xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString const&, bool, int, xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString const&, xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString const&, xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString const&, xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString const&, bool, xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString const&, xalanc_1_12::FormatterListener::eFormat, bool, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:501: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesDOMWalker::traverse(xercesc_4_0::DOMNode*)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/TargetRTS//libdhf.a(DOMImpl.o): in function `dhf::DOMImpl::selectNode(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:510: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesParserLiaison::XercesParserLiaison(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:517: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XercesParserLiaison::createDocument(xercesc_4_0::DOMDocument const*, bool, bool, bool)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:522: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XalanDOMString::XalanDOMString(char const*, xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&, unsigned long)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:527: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XPathEvaluator::XPathEvaluator(xercesc_4_0::MemoryManager&)'
xxxxxxxxxgcc-12.2.0/../binutils-2.36.1/bin/ld: xxxxxxxxx/DOMImpl.cc:528: undefined reference to `xalanc_1_12::XPathEvaluator::selectSingleNode(xalanc_1_12::DOMSupport&, xalanc_1_12::XalanNode*, char16_t const*, xalanc_1_12::XalanElement const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my  cmake options:

```
CC=gcc-12.2.0/bin/gcc CXX=gcc-12.2.0/bin/g++ CFLAGS=-O3 CXXFLAGS=-O3 cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=xalan-c/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -Dmessage-loader=inmemory -Dtranscoder=default xalan-c
```

It seems something may be inconsistent with my build options, any idea to fix this?

Thanks very much!

Chunde

Answer (score 0):

Eventually figured out the issue, this was because Xalan need to link to Xercesc, without specifying the path to the version 4.0.0 of Xercesc, it will link to the default version at system path. So I used

> -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

variable to set that, the new cmake command looks like this:

```
CC=gcc-12.2.0/bin/gcc CXX=gcc-12.2.0/bin/g++ CFLAGS=-O3 CXXFLAGS=-O3 cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=xxx/xerces-c_4.0.0/ -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=xalan-c/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -Dmessage-loader=inmemory -Dtranscoder=default xalan-c
```